# I would like to create a custom Ubuntu-based distro, how do I remaster?

Tags: 15.04

I would Like to remaster Ubuntu 15.04 into my own Linux distro is there a easy way? I would also like to know a list of different ways to create my own distro varying in difficulty.

Comment: Use the debian-live scripts - http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual.en.html See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: This may help: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd). Creating your on ISO should mean that you can install your customized distro onto other computers

Comment: See the second answer from WIlf's link.